# How to send a file to the Recently Deleted folder in the Files app?

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

I am using the following properties to ensure my app exposes its documents in the Files app in case the user wants to share them or back them up:

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true />
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true />
```

However, when I use `FileManager.default.removeItem` to remove a file, it doesn't appear in Recently Deleted in the File app, it's just gone.

Do only user-removed files go there? Can I remove an item "to recycle bin"?

Similarly, when my application is uninstalled, all its documents go with it without landing in the Recently Deleted directory, but this is clearly by design and not changeable.